# Can't pip install older version of Jinja2

Tags: python, installation, pip, jinja2

I'm trying to `pip install Jinja2==2.6` (current version is 2.7.3) but keep getting an error.

I've made sure that it exists on pypi yet it still doesn't find it. If you want to see the pypi  webpage [click here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/2.6)

```
$ pip install Jinja2==2.6
Collecting Jinja2==2.6
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jinja2==2.6 (from versions: 2.7.3)
No distributions matching the version for Jinja2==2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I have founded this:

> Jinja2 works with Python 2.6.x, 2.7.x and >= 3.3. If you are using
>   Python 3.2 you can use an older release of Jinja2 (2.6) as support for
>   Python 3.2 was dropped in Jinja2 version 2.7.

May be it could help. Visit [Jinja Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/intro/)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had previously changed my pip.conf file to search for packages in a private location. Probably too specific to be helpful to others.

Answer (score -1):

You are not running it as `sudo` try:

```
 sudo pip install Jinja2==2.6
```

and check your internet status.

Comment: If `sudo` was an issue there would be an error asking for admin privileges.

Comment: Not entirely it will still run but it could also popup a message involving no distribution because it will not be allowed to pass through some firewalls

Comment: Sudo is not an adequate solution, for it could change where on disk packages are installed.

If you still abide by your answer, you should modify it to state this issue could also be caused by the user being unable to reach pip servers. Sudo may have been a patch that worked in your specific network because your *nix user didn't have internet access.